# Perl accessing/changing deep hash by array list

Tags: perl, hash

I want to delete an element of a hash(of any depth) which has the first key as `$key[0]`, the second key as `$key[1]` etc, until `@key` is finished.

For example, if `@key=(23,56,78)` then i want to manipulate `$hash{23}{56}{78}`.
I don't know beforehand how many elements `@key` has.

I have been trying to use the following:

```
my %the_path;
my $temp=\%the_path;
for(my $cline=0;$cline<=$#keys;$cline++){
     my $cfolder=$keys[$cline];
     $temp->{$cfolder}={};
     $temp=$temp->{$cfolder};
}
```

But, I'm not sure how to manipulate the element at here. How do I do that?

Comment: scalar @key gives you the length, doesn't it?

Comment: sounds like homework. have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: this is not homework and i have tried myself, yes.

Comment: well what did you try? Perhaps we can show where you went wrong.

Comment: So what have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: You're talking about a hash, but referring to arrays ($key[0])?  Not sure what you mean there.  Can you post a sample of what you've tried?

Comment: @Jerome: he meant he couldn't code for just one possible length, e.g. `delete $the_path{ $keys[0] }{ $keys[1] }{ $keys[2] };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Data::Diver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Diver) exists for exactly this purpose.

```
my $last_hash = Data::Diver::Dive( \%hash, @keys[0..$#keys-1] );
if ($last_hash) { delete $last_hash->{ $keys[-1] } }
```

Comment: Don't you mean:
my $hash_ref=\%hash;
my $last_hash = Data::Diver::Dive( $hash_ref, @keys[0..$#keys-1] );
if ($last_hash) { delete $last_hash->{ $keys[-1] }; }

?

Answer (score 1):

You need to traverse the tree of hashrefs down using the next key value in the list as a key to traverse to, till you hit the second to last key in the list; then delete the hashref value associated with the last key.

```
my $hash_ptr = $my_hash_ref;
foreach my $key_num (0..$#keys) {
    my $key = $keys[$key_num];
    if (exists $hash_ptr->{$key}) {
        if ($key_num == $#keys) {
            delete $hash_ptr->{$key};
        } else {
            $hash_ptr = $hash_ptr->{$key}; # Go down 1 level
        }
    } else {
        last;
    }
}
```

Note: this does NOT delete any elements of the hashref tree above the last one, even if they don't contain anymore keys. In other words it deletes 1 node, NOT an entire path - it does not, in Evan's words, prune the tree. If that is not what you meant, please clarify.

Comment: Just retested the code - it works. Not sure what the downvote was for

Comment: you have a bug; no delete should occur for `{a=>{c=>42}}` with keys a,b,c  (but I didn't downvote)

Comment: It's simpler if you do the delete after the loop, e.g. the tersified: `my $hp = $root || {}; $hp = $hp->{$_} || {} for @keys[-@keys..-2]; delete $hp->{ $keys[-1] };`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with recursion:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash = { foo => { here => 'there', bar => { baz => 100 } } };

## mutates input
sub delete_hash {
  my ( $hash, $keys ) = @_;
  my $key = shift @$keys;
  die "Stopped recursing $key doesn't exist"
    unless exists $hash->{$key}
  ;
  scalar @$keys
    ? delete_hash( $hash->{$key}, $keys )
    : delete $hash->{$key}
  ;
}

delete_hash( $hash, [qw/foo bar/] );

use XXX;
YYY $hash;
```

The stack does grow and function calls have a price. You can aparently mitigate that with perl's version of TCO with this code:

```
if (scalar @$keys) {
  @_=($hash->{$key}, $keys);
  goto &delete_hash;
}
else {
  delete $hash->{$key}
}
```

And, it should also noted that none of this code prunes the tree: if you delete `[qw/foo bar baz/]` then `bar` will be an empty hash ref.

```
foo:
  bar: {}
  here: there
```

Comment: you COULD, of course, simply unroll the recursion into a loop if you have performance concerns (in which case you get my answer :) ). Good wording on "prune" - i'll steal it, sorry :)

Comment: You can always eliminate sub-calls, depends on your goal. Maybe I'll write a benchmark with the goto variant.